# How to create a drag and drop form builder?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, workflow

I am thinking of creating a drag and drop form builder kind of product (Just for learning :)).
Existing form builders references like JotForm, Wufoo, Orbeon form builders.

I am very eager to know which technology can be used and how to create such products.It will be great helpful for any reference, tutorial to create such drag and drop form builders.

Comment: What backend logic you have followed for multiple use, did you use json column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery UI has a great start for drag and drop items. Check out http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ to get started and post back if you run into any question/problems.

Comment: :Thank you very much.I have gone through the website it is very helpful.Can you please tell me which IDE or tool can be used to develop such kind of product?

Comment: PHPStorm/IntelliJ idea are both great choices for programming in php/html/javascript. Dreamweaver may be a better option if you're looking to use more of a GUI interface though. Hardly relevant to the question though ;)

Comment: Thanks Joe.The IntelliJIdea seems i need to purchase, so i thought of using Eclipse IDE to do the hands-on.